# Is it possible to update Google Product Search mappings with the Bigcommerce Python API?

Tags: python, api, bigcommerce

Bigcommerce provides a restful API in a couple different languages. I am currently working with the Python API package. We use it to update values on products when certain conditions are met.

The one thing that we really need to update is the 'GPS Enabled' feature, basically make an item available for Google Shopping. We have a specific reason. In the Google Product Search Mappings Resource the field is called 'enable' and it takes a boolean value.

We can pull the google product data with a call like this:

```
api.Products.get(id).google_mappings()
```

Unfortunatley it looks like Bigcommerce doesn't allow us to update anything for Google Product Search. Can this be verified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time the Google Product Search Mappings resource is read only and can only list the mapping properties for a given product ID.